# Number Format Exception in java at run time

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm currently developing my own calculator and I'm getting an `NumberFormatException` when I press the plus button inside it:-

```
if(e.getSource() == p) {
    String a[] = new String[2];
    double d[] = new double[2]; 
    for(int i =0; i<2; i++) {
        a[i] = tf.getText();
        d[i] = Double.parseDouble(a[i]);
        System.out.println("First array is "+d[i]);
        sum = sum + d[i];
        tf.setText(null);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting what the number format exception is i searched it's telling me that my string is empty but what i need to do now.

[please click here for errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtA7S.png)

Comment: I suggest you debug your program in your debugger to see why the text area is empty.

Comment: The programme runs correctly but when I press the plus button the exception strikes

Comment: The program isn't working correctly if the text you expect to not be empty, is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse `+` inside `Double.parseDouble(String string)`

If the string does not contain a parsable double it throw `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Ok now I get it I m converting my string into double but I'm inputting an integer variable just when I inputted an double variable it didn't gave me error

Comment: But can you tell me that how can I check that the inputted number is an integer or an double or of any other kind

Comment: @devjoshi print value of `tf.getText();` what is it ?

Comment: you're setting `tf.setText(null);` for next iteration of loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are entering the input as 1+2, so when you click plus, the second number which you are storing is null hence the error

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve your problem

```
if(e.getSource() == p) {
    String a[] = new String[2];
    double d[] = new double[2]; 
    for(int i =0; i<2; i++) {
        a[i] = tf.getText();
         if(a[i].contains("[a-zA-Z]+") == false){
           d[i] = Double.parseDouble(a[i]);
           System.out.println("First array is "+d[i]);
           sum = sum + d[i];
           tf.setText(null);
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I'm converting the string into double if the user enters double then no problem but if the user enters any of the integer then there will be exception

Comment: You can cast integer into double , It will resolve your issue .